# How to write Console ouput to both console and file in C#?

Tags: c#, console

I have a simple console application, and I have used `Console.WriteLine` in many places to display to the user the activities being performed. But, at the end I want to save all the Console output to a log file also. Currently, I have something like this:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(LOG_DIRECTORY)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(LOG_DIRECTORY);
}

long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
string logFilename = ticks.ToString() + ".txt";
string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + LOG_DIRECTORY + "\\" + logFilename;
FileStream ostream = null;
StreamWriter writer = null;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

try
{
    ostream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    writer = new StreamWriter(ostream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot open {0} for writing.", logFilename);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return;
}

Console.SetOut(writer);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

Console.SetOut(oldOut);
writer.Close();
ostream.Close();

Console.WriteLine("\n\nDone!");
```

The point is that this will print the stuff directly into the file and nothing is printed in the Console. Is there any way to workaround this? Please note that I need the `Console.WriteLine` output to be directly in real time to be written to the console, whereas, for writing to a log file, it can be done at the end of the program, where nearly everything else is finished.

Comment: You can either write your own component or use a logging tool such as NLog that can write to multiple outputs simultanously. We use NLog to write to the debugger, console, CSV and buffered emails (for auto-error reporting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either create your own component to write to multiple outputs or you can use a logging tool such as NLog. This can be configured such that in the `<targets>` section you have something like;

```
<target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger" layout="${level}>${message} (${exception:format=ToString})"/>
<target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} - ${message}" />
<target name="FullCSVFile" xsi:type="File"  fileName="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}\YourApp\YourApp-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.csv">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
    <column name="Index" layout="${counter}" />
    <column name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" />
    <column name="Time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <column name="Severity" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
    <column name="Location" layout="${callsite:className=False:fileName=True:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=False}" />
    <column name="Detail" layout="${message}" />
    <column name="Exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

Then in the `rules` section, you'd have;

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debugger" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="FullCSVFile" />
```

To actually do the write operation, you'd have something like the following in your C# code;

```
// at a class level;
private static NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

// later in code that writes to both targets...
_logger.Info("Something happened!");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this writes to a debugger and console, not to a file and console, right?

Comment: @typos, apologies, I've updated my answer to write out to a CSV as well. This comes from a config we use in our test and  production systems and works quite well once up and running. NLog can be configured to write to a number of end points such as SQL Server, emails, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about saving console output in variable like `string array` or `List<string>` ? Then do the `File.WriteAllText(filepath, consoleOutputArray);`

I mean this way:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> textStorage = new List<string>();

            string exampleData = "Ford Mustang";

            Console.WriteLine(exampleData);

            SaveOutput(ref textStorage, exampleData);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C://Desktop//MyFolder", textStorage);

        }
        public static void SaveOutput(ref List<string> textStorage, string output)
        {
            textStorage.Add(output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I save console output to variable?

Comment: Just assign string to it.

Answer (score 0):

After each console output store the output in a list and at the end of the program update the log with the details.

```
var list = new List<string>;
string xyz = "message";
Console.WriteLine(xyz);
list.add(xyz);
foreach (object o in list)
{
     StreamWriter sw = null;
            String Logfile = "C:\ExceptionLog.txt";
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(LogFile))
            {
                sw = File.CreateText(LogFile);


            }
            else
            {
                sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\ExceptionLog.txt");
            }

            sw.WriteLine(o);
            sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for simple scenarios - when I'm prototyping or researching something and don't want to worry about losing the console output accidentally.

```
// run this at application start
using var multiWriter = new MultiTextWriter(File.CreateText("my_log_file"), Console.Out);
Console.SetOut(multiWriter);

public class MultiTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly TextWriter[] _writers;

    public MultiTextWriter(params TextWriter[] writers)
    {
        _writers = writers;
    }

    // abstract in parent; most of the time you don't need it, though
    // xml stuff needs it, so you may have to implement it
    public override Encoding Encoding => throw new NotImplementedException();

    // technically I think this is the only thing you need to override
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < _writers.Length; index++)
        {
            _writers[index].Write(value);
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string? value)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < _writers.Length; index++)
        {
            _writers[index].Write(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < _writers.Length; index++)
        {
            _writers[index].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```